# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'year' ( occurs when iterating through a list trying to convert dates )

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am trying to convert the birthdays that I have in a list to years in age.  Dates are strings.

bday_list: ['1990-01-01', '1991-01-01', '1992-01-01']

to

bday_list: [30, 29, 28]

Using python3, my code to convert is:

```
for i in range(bday_list_length):

    pd.to_datetime('today').year - pd.to_datetime(bday_list[i]).year
```

however, when i run this: i get the following error:

*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/DBlytics/notebook/poc/ageData.py", line 60, in 
    pd.to_datetime('today').year - pd.to_datetime(bday_list[i]).year
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'year'*

However, when i run the following outside of the loop, it converts.

```
    pd.to_datetime('today').year - pd.to_datetime(bday_list[i]).year
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try `print(repr(bday_list[i]))` and the last one you see is the one that is problematic. For instance, `pd.to_datetime(None).year` raises the same error.

Comment: Thanks!  The error was with a 'null' entry in the list.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @thehungrypanda121 - then use `pd.to_datetime(bday_list, errors='coerce')`, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
bday_list = ['1990-01-01', '1991-01-01', '1992-01-01']
for date in bday_list:
     print(datetime.today().year - datetime.strptime(date,'%Y-%m-%d').year)
```

Using datetime, I am extracting the current date year subtracted by the year extracted from the string in bday_list after converting it in date format using strptime()

Comment: Thank you for you response.  The error was in my data.  When the null value was iterated into pd.to_datetime(bday_list[i]).year, it threw the error.  Your code also works as well as more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

In pandas working with arrays, so remove `[i]` only and also add `errors='coerce'` for convert bad data - solution convert values to `NaT`:

```
bday_list = ['1990-01-01', '1991-01-01', '1992-01-01', 'wrong']

print (pd.to_datetime(bday_list, errors='coerce'))
DatetimeIndex(['1990-01-01', '1991-01-01', '1992-01-01', 'NaT'], 
dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

---

```
out = pd.to_datetime('today').year - pd.to_datetime(bday_list, errors='coerce').year
print (out)
Float64Index([30.0, 29.0, 28.0, nan], dtype='float64')
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use plain python to solve the above task. There is no need to call pandas when looping through your list. Furthermore, you can use list comprehension.

```
from typing import List
import datetime as dt


bday_list: List[str] = ["1990-01-01", "1991-01-01", "1992-01-01"]
bday_list_dates = [dt.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d") for x in bday_list]
today = dt.date.today()
year_of_age = [today.year - x.year for x in bday_list_dates]
print(year_of_age)
```

Answer (score 0):

`import datetime
import pandas as pd
date_list = ['1990-01-01', '1991-01-01', '1992-01-01']
date_list = [pd.to_datetime(date) for date in date_list]
age_list = [int(datetime.now().strftime('%Y')) - int(date.strftime('%Y')) for date in date_list]`

It's easy!!, just use the above code..